# Change elements orientation from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android

i want to have two buttons with vertical orientation when the device is in portrait mode,and in horizontal orientation when it is in landscape.How will i get it with only an .xml file?May i use something like "styles.xml" and say that if i have portrait do this and if i have landscape do the other one?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The layouts in /res/layout are applied to both portrait and landscape.

To use a different layout in landscape, create a folder /res/layout-land and create another xml file here with the same name. Android will automatically choose the layout corresponding to the current screen orientation.

EDIT :

If you cannot create a second folder or are concerned about performances, then you can override the onConfigurationChanged() method, as [explained here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

Comment: are you sure this is the only way?i m asking because today this was one exercise in my university exams,but i only could have a layout folder.There is no way to use something like when i want to change the color of a button when pressed etc?

Comment: I edited my answer. It's not the only way, but it's the easiest way.